# linq group by object

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, group-by

I have an object which contains a list of another object as follow:

```
    class cl
    {
      List<a> a ;
      public List<a> listofA
      {
      get; set;
      }
    }

    class a
    {
    //other properties
       string comment ;
      public string comment
      {
      get; set;
      }
    }
```

Now how do i make a linq query to see if comment is of some string here is my query:

```
  var query = (from c in scope.Extent<cl>()
                         where  c.Date >= dateFrom && c.Date < dateTo
                         && c.Actions.Where(a => (a.comment== "") )
                         orderby c.Date.Value.Date
                         group c by c.Date.Value.Date into grpDate
                          select new { grpDate.Key, items = grpDate });
```

but i get error saying :

```
Error   15  Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>
Error   13  Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're using `c.Actions.Where`.  This returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, not a `bool`, but you're doing a check for your where clause which expects a boolean value.

You can most likely solve this by using `Any` instead of `Where`:

```
 var query = (from c in scope.Extent<cl>()
                     where  c.Date >= dateFrom && c.Date < dateTo
                     && c.Actions.Any(a => (a.comment== "") )
                     orderby c.Date.Value.Date
                     group c by c.Date.Value.Date into grpDate
                      select new { grpDate.Key, items = grpDate });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the result of `c.Actions.Where(a => (a.comment== "") )`, which is `IEnumerable`, as a `bool`. If I understand correctly, you may want to use `Any` instead of `Where` in this expression - or other aggregation function like `All`.

Answer (score 1):

`c.Actions.Where(a => (a.comment== "") )` returns a list of actions, but you're using it as a boolean (with `&&`).  You should either use `.Any()` to test whether there is something that matches, or refactor so that the true/false tests are separate from the `Where()`

I'd give more specific advice, but I'm not sure why you're comparing to an empty string.