# Grouping and setting conditions for list query

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, group-by, linq-to-objects

I have a list of Status objects carrying int value and datetime in format of

> Tue Sep 30 21:22:02 +0000 2014

Code:

```
public class Status
{
    public string created_at { get; set; }

    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I would like to display this information on chart, but for the last 7 days only.

How can I group objects by date in C# and manage to get this information? I would know how to do it in SQL, but I am not familiar with LINQ.

Comment: Possible duper: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403483/linq-group-by-object

Comment: Why do you store DateTime in string but not in DateTime?

Comment: 1. Why is your date stored as a `string` instead of a `DateTime`? 2. I'm confused... do you actually need a `GroupBy` or a `Where`?

Comment: It is the way JSON feed is retrieved. There are several statuses posted on the same day, so I would like to group them and display their total value per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to group Status to sum or count some other field on your class, so you can get a total of something by day.

If so, given the following example

```
        List<Status> statusList = new List<Status>();
        statusList.Add(new Status() { Value = 12, CreatedAt = "Tue Sep 30 21:22:02 +0000 2014" });
        statusList.Add(new Status() { Value = 11, CreatedAt = "Tue Sep 30 21:22:02 +0000 2014" });
        statusList.Add(new Status() { Value = 10, CreatedAt = "Tue Sep 30 21:22:02 +0000 2014" });
        statusList.Add(new Status() { Value = 9, CreatedAt = "Sat Sep 27 21:22:02 +0000 2014" });
        statusList.Add(new Status() { Value = 8, CreatedAt = "Fri Sep 26 21:22:02 +0000 2014" });
        statusList.Add(new Status() { Value = 7, CreatedAt = "Thu Sep 25 21:22:02 +0000 2014" });
        statusList.Add(new Status() { Value = 6, CreatedAt = "Wed Sep 24 21:22:02 +0000 2014" });
        statusList.Add(new Status() { Value = 5, CreatedAt = "Tue Sep 23 21:22:02 +0000 2014" });
        statusList.Add(new Status() { Value = 4, CreatedAt = "Mon Sep 22 21:22:02 +0000 2014" });
        statusList.Add(new Status() { Value = 3, CreatedAt = "Sun Sep 21 21:22:02 +0000 2014" });
        statusList.Add(new Status() { Value = 2, CreatedAt = "Sat Sep 20 21:22:02 +0000 2014" });
        statusList.Add(new Status() { Value = 1, CreatedAt = "Fri Sep 19 21:22:02 +0000 2014" });



        var groups = from status in statusList
                  let date = DateTime.ParseExact(status.CreatedAt, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                  group status by date into g
                  where g.Key.Date >= DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)
                  select g;

        foreach (IGrouping<DateTime, Status> group in groups)
        {
            DateTime day = group.Key;
            int countOfValues = group.Select(g => g.Value).Count();
            Console.WriteLine("Day: {0}", day.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("countOfValues: {0}", countOfValues.ToString());
        }
```

It prints:

```
Day: 9/30/2014 4:22:02 PM
countOfValues: 3 //Three entries on Sep 30...
Day: 9/27/2014 4:22:02 PM
countOfValues: 1
Day: 9/26/2014 4:22:02 PM
countOfValues: 1
Day: 9/25/2014 4:22:02 PM
countOfValues: 1
Day: 9/24/2014 4:22:02 PM
countOfValues: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add following to yours where condition then yours SP/SQL Query will return only records within 7 days.

```
datediff(day, created_at, getdate()) < 7
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using int (it's pretty bad, but ok..) then first of all you must convert int to datetime: search on google `int to datetime`.

The second step's to implement `TimeSpan` and use overriden operators for `Datetime` and `TimeSpan`.

```
public bool LaterThan7Days(int valueFromClass)
{
    DateTime myTime = //here convert valueFromClass to Datetime, search in google please
    TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(7,0 , 0, 0); //days, hours ,mins, seconds
    DateTime timeToCompare = myTime + t;
    return timeToCompare > DateTime.Now;
}
```

and the query should looks like:

```
var query = from Status in yourContext
            where LaterThan7Days(Status.value)
            select Status;

query.ToList().Foreach(p=> Console.WriteLine(p.created_at));
```